# Jquery if / else after form sent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a connexion form, in a bloc, basically `visibility:hidden` when the form is sent the page reloading.

But the bloc back to hidden. I would like to keep the `visibility: visible` after the page reloaded. But actually, this code doesn't work

(the variable $styleblocconnexion is set by the PHP treatment if something went wrong)

```
<script>
    $("#connexion-button").click(function () {
        $('#bloc-connexion').css("visibility", "visible");
        $('#fond-bloc-connexion').css("visibility", "visible");
    });

    $("#submitconnect").click(function () {
        var styleblocconnexion = <? php if (isset($styleblocconnexion)) { echo $styleblocconnexion; } else { echo false; } ?>;
        if (styleblocconnexion != false) {
            $('#bloc-connexion').css("visibility", "visible");
            $('#fond-bloc-connexion').css("visibility", "visible");
        }
    });
</script>
```

And here is the code from PHP treatment who's setting $styleblocconnexion

```
if (isset($_POST['submitconnect'])) {
    $emailconnect = htmlspecialchars($_POST['emailconnect']);
    $mdpconnect = sha1($_POST['mdpconnect']);
    if (filter_var($emailconnect, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $reqemailexist = $bdd -> prepare("SELECT * FROM membres WHERE email = ?");
        $reqemailexist -> execute(array($emailconnect));
        $resultemailexist = $reqemailexist -> rowCount();
        if ($resultemailexist == 1) {
            $resultemailexistfetch = $reqemailexist -> fetch();
            if ($mdpconnect == $resultemailexistfetch['mdp']) {
                $_SESSION['id'] = $resultemailexistfetch['id'];
                $_SESSION['email'] = $resultemailexistfetch['email'];
                header("Location: index.php?id=".$_SESSION['id']);
            }
            else {
                $msgerreurformconnect = "Mot de passe incorrect";
                $styleblocconnexion = "visible";
            }
        }
        else {
            $msgerreurformconnect = "Cette adresse email ne correspond à         aucun compte.";
            $styleblocconnexion = "visible";
        }
    }
    else {
        $msgerreurformconnect = "Email invalide";
        $styleblocconnexion = "visible";
    }
}
```

As you see, $styleblocconnexion is set only if something went wrong.

Comment: What is  `$styleblocconnexion` returning can you please tell

Comment: Please go read [ask], and how to create a [mcve]. We have no idea what the server-side `$styleblocconnexion` is supposed to contain or where it is supposed to come from, so we can't possibly answer your question.

Comment: I think the problem is in this line 
`var styleblocconnexion = <?php if(isset($styleblocconnexion)) { echo $styleblocconnexion; } else { echo false; } ?>`
check in console what value you are getting of `styleblocconnexion` may be this will help you

Comment: _"I would like to keep the visibility:visible after the page reloaded"_ - so you want it to show without the user having to click anywhere first? Well then wrapping this in a `click` handler makes no sense in the first place, obviously ... you simply want to wrap those two lines that set the visibility (or one line, `$('#bloc-connexion, #fond-bloc-connexion').css("visibility", "visible");`) into document ready, and output that dependent on whether `$styleblocconnexion` is set.

Answer (score 0):

I finnaly did it with the document.ready :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        var styleblocconnexion = "<?php if(isset($styleblocconnexion)) {  echo $styleblocconnexion; } else { echo false; } ?>";
        if (styleblocconnexion != false)
        {
            $('#bloc-connexion').css("visibility", "visible");
            $('#fond-bloc-connexion').css("visibility", "visible");
        }

        });
```

Thank you